# ssh connection issues from 5.3 client to 7.4 server

Tags: centos, ssh

We have a setup like this:

- client openssh 5.3 on centos 6
- nginxplus stream proxy on centos 7 (proxies custom ssh port to gitlab server port 22)
- gitlab server which runs openssh 7.4

We cannot ssh from the client to the server. We can connect to the ssh server from other places. We can connect to the custom tcp port and while running the ssh client command we see a tcp connect on the port. But no data is proxied to the gitlab server, probably because the client doesn't supply data.

We also tried to start an ssh session to the client host with a port forward to the proxy/gitlab server so we could connect from the client node IP, but with a newer client. This does work, so we don't think it's a firewall or denyhost-like issue.
We renewed the ssh host keys on the client node, but this also has no effect.

While connecting we see in tcpdump it doesn't start to negotiate a ssh protocol. We think it might have to do with the client version, or maybe we are missing a configuration setting, but I can't find out what.

```
[root@clienthost ~]#  ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitlab.test.fqdn -p $CUSTOMPORT -vv
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for gitlab.test.fqdn
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.test.fqdn [a.b.c.d] port $CUSTOMPORT.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
```

As far as I understand, this has mostly to do with the old rsa 1 protocol and shouldn't really matter for rsa 2.
Privileges for the id_rsa file are `0400`
Btw it also does not work for other users than root.

ssh client config:

```
Host gitlab.test.fqdn
  HostName gitlab.test.fqdn
  User git
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
  Port $CUSTOMPORT
```

*Edit after comments on the id_rsa file properties*

Also fixed that the file command reports the id_rsa as an ASCII text file and now it reports a pem rsa private key file

Anyone any ideas on what I'm missing or could be wrong?

Comment: are you sure `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` is a proper private key ? what does `file /root/.ssh/id_rsa` gave you ?

Comment: I use the same private key for the login via the port forward as the direct login. However, when I do it on the client server, I get:
`# file .ssh/id_rsa 
.ssh/id_rsa: ASCII text
`
while on my local machine I get
`.ssh/id_rsa: PEM RSA private key`

Comment: it should be **PEM RSA private key** (as showned by trace you provide)

Comment: Thank you, looking into this, at the moment even private keys generated on the node itself are marked as ascii text, so I need to find out how to fix that.

Comment: added custom lines from another node to the magic file and now file recognizes it as a pem private rsa key. Still the same result as in my original post when trying to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had ssl_preread enabled in nginx, which apparently prevents the server-first protocol and version announcement.
After turning this off the server does send the protocol and version first and everything works as desired.

telcoM's answer was a huge help in this, so thank you! But I wanted to post the specific configuration change as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `nc -v gitlab.test.fqdn $CUSTOMPORT` or `telnet gitlab.test.fqdn $CUSTOMPORT`, you should immediately get a SSH server version string back if the proxy works in a way that's directly compatible with SSH.

The string should look like this:

```
SSH-2.0-<something...>
```

If the proxy has been accidentally misconfigured to expect HTTP protocol, the connection will succeed but there will be no initial response. In HTTP, the client is expected to speak first, as opposed to the SSH protocol which requires the server side to speak first.

(A HTTP-proxy-aware client *could* then use HTTP `CONNECT` request to get connected to a specified port at a specified destination, but that would allow the client to choose the destination of the proxied connection, which is apparently not what you want here.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I do that I only get the ssh protocol reply from the server after I first send my own protocol. It does seem to move on in the connection negotiation by offering a set of ciphers.
So I seem to have 2 options:
- make sure that the client offers a protocol (the less ssh-way of doing things)
- make sure the server offers the protocol (so this is preferred)

Comment: When I directly connect to port 22 on the gitlab server it does offer the ssh protocol. The nginx proxy is setup as a tcp stream, but apparently it does not forward this offer.

Comment: Looks like the nginx proxy might be unsuitable for proxying SSH, then.

Comment: Or perhaps its configuration is not quite right for this task. I don't know much about using nginx for proxying.

Comment: Since this is an nginx issue, I'll drop a ticket with their support and update this post afterwards.